# How can I save models in Syncfusion Blazor components after selecting languages using SfMultiSelect?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, syncfusion

I'm working with Syncfusion Blazor components and I'm having some issues saving the model, for instance:

```
...
<GridColumns>
     ...
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Project.ProgrammingLanguages) HeaderText="Programming Languages">
         <Template>
             @string.Join(",", (context as IEnumerable<ProgrammingLanguage>)?.Select(pl => pl.Name) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
        </Template>
        <EditTemplate>
              @{
                   Project project = context as Project ?? new();

                   void HandleLanguageSelection(MultiSelectChangeEventArgs<ProgrammingLanguage[]> selectedValues)
                   {
                         if (selectedValues is not null)
                             project.ProgrammingLanguages = selectedValues.Value;
                   }
             }
           <SfMultiSelect TValue="ProgrammingLanguage[]" TItem="ProgrammingLanguage" Placeholder="Select a language" DataSource="@allLanguages">
                   <MultiSelectEvents TValue="ProgrammingLanguage[]" TItem="ProgrammingLanguage" ValueChange="@HandleLanguageSelection" />
                   <MultiSelectFieldSettings Text="@nameof(ProgrammingLanguage.Name)" />
           </SfMultiSelect>
      </EditTemplate>
   </GridColumn>
</GridColumns>
...

@code {
    IEnumerable<ProgrammingLanguage>? allLanguages;

    [Inject]
    public IProgrammingLanguageService ProgrammingLanguageService { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => allLanguages = await ProgrammingLanguageService.GetAllModelsAsync();
    ...
}
```

After selecting some languages, "edit mode" closes on its own without saving models

I also tried to implement it this way:

```
<SfMultiSelect TValue="IEnumerable<ProgrammingLanguage>" TItem="ProgrammingLanguage" Placeholder="Select a language" DataSource="@allLanguages" @bind-Value="project.ProgrammingLanguages">
         <MultiSelectFieldSettings Text="@nameof(ProgrammingLanguage.Name)"/>
</SfMultiSelect>
```

What should I do? I tried to use other events for saving models and it doesn't work as well

Edited: If use the second way then It'll be such a mistake:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.ArgumentException: There is no
> tracked object with id '5'.

Answer (score 1):

**Query: I'm working with Syncfusion Blazor components and I'm having some issues saving the model**

In this, you have not defined the Value property for the components (SfMultiSelect) in the EditTemplate. So kindly define the @bind-Value property to MultiSelect component to save the changes properly in Grid.

Refer our UG documentation for your reference : https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/cell-edit-types#using-multiselect-dropdown-in-edittemplate

**Query: After selecting some languages, "edit mode" closes on its own without saving models I also tried to implement it this way**

Currently multiselect will not support direct assigning of IEnumerable generic interface, so you are facing the reported issue. Instead, use IEnumerble types such as List and arrays at your end.